# SQL SELECT returns array but PHP considers that as null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, null

I'm selecting something in mySQL via PHP and that command returns some array (which is right), but when I put that returning SELECT inside if condition and ask if it is returning null than PHP says it is returning null (which is not right, because it is returning array)

```
include '../db.php'; // my config

function select($command) {
  global $db;
  $sql = "".$command."";
  $sqlDone = $db -> prepare($sql);
  $sqlDone -> execute();
  $data = $sqlDone -> fetchAll();
  return $data;
}

$select = "SELECT likes.ID, likes.ID_user, likes.ID_post FROM likes WHERE likes.ID_user = '53' AND likes.ID_post = '2'"

if (select($select) == null) { // goes throw this
  print_r(select($select)); // returns array
} else {
    echo 'not null';
}
```

I tried to use !is_null and it doesn't work anyway.
I tried to put that select command with same values directly inside phpmyadmin and it returns array, so I'm confused. Can you help me out?

[image: Screenshot of phpmyadmin]

Comment: Don't you want to `print_r` the data if not null  instead of just printing *"not null"* ?

Comment: nah, that print_r is there just because of testing. It returns array same as in that if condition

Comment: You should use strict equality (`===`) instead of (`==`). An empty array is "falsy" in PHP

Comment: I don't really understand the purpose of your `select()` function, why do you need it? Seems needlessly complicated to me, and a few of the lines in there do nothing at all.

Comment: @Darragh Enright When I use this than it goes always for not null

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I need that return there, because I'm checking what it is returning

Comment: Sorry, the point I was trying to make is that this is why PHP thinks an empty array is `null`. Just making a general point, not one specific to your broader question - I should have been clearer about that.

Comment: fetchAll() will return an empty array, assuming there is no failure.  If you test for array length (assuming you're ignoring error messages) with count(), that would fit better with the documentation of the function  http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: oh, yeah you are right, no problem.

Comment: What happens if you don't wrap the ids in single quotes? I seem to recall seeing an issue like this before with MySQL/PDO but I cannot remember for sure. In any case, you are expecting results so there might be an issue there. Since you are using prepared statements you might consider positional parameters.

Comment: @SenTisso I'm not talking about the return, I'm talking about the entire function. It's unnecessary. Check out my answer

Comment: @DarraghEnright nothing at all

Answer (score 1):

PDO's `fetchAll()` returns an array, if there are no results, it returns an empty array (not NULL).

Just use `empty()`

```
$return = select($select); //put this into a variable, because if you don't, you'll query the database twice and may get different results.
if (empty($return)) { // goes throw this
  print_r($return); // returns array
} else {
    echo 'not null';
}
```

---

Side note, your function doesn't really do anything special. You could achieve the same thing with this:

```
$return = $db->prepare($select)->execute()->fetchAll();
```

If you used a PDO wrapper, it could be even shorter. For example, using my own wrapper [GrumpyPDO](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO), you would use

```
$return = $db->all($select);
```

then if you had variables to pass to the query, you would do

```
$select = "SELECT likes.ID, likes.ID_user, likes.ID_post FROM likes WHERE likes.ID_user = ? AND likes.ID_post = ?"
$return = $db->all($select, [$userid, $postid]);
```

Comment: Didn't you mean just 'empty()' ? without exclamation mark? because '!empty()' is checking if it has something in it.

Comment: @SenTisso Yes, my bad. It confused me because `print_r($return)` will literally return nothing if that if statement is met.

Comment: So, I'm officially id*ot I was using ajax when clicking on button and I had some mess there and I was sending bad data and that PHP is working as it was, but anyways thank you for your time.